# Discord Bot Timer saying that something valid is not, is there a way to fix this?

Tags: javascript, timer, discord, bots

I have made a timer command, but what happens is when I put in a valid time it says it is invalid, could someone help me?

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'timer':      
            let time = (args[1]);
                if(!time){
                return message.reply("You didn't specify a time!");
            }    
            message.reply(`Your timer has started for ${ms(ms(time))}`);  
            setTimeout(function(){                 
                message.reply(`your timer has stopped`)
            }, ms(time));    
            if (isNaN(time)) return message.reply('That is not a valid number');      
    }
});
```

[image: Here is what is happening]

Comment: What is `ms`, is that an external package or an internal function you created? At first sight it looks 7s got rejected because it's not a number, while 7 and 7000 while accepted just fine.

Comment: @MrBobby I'm not sure what it is, I have a bunch of code from tutorials and I just scrapped together this code.

Comment: Well what you have looks like it works fine to me. It seems that what you scrapped together works off milliseconds and 7s isn't a valid number as it's a string. Please let me know if I'm not understanding it correctly.